# COUNT IF NOT NULL DATE in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get results from 2 columns where app_id value is not null and paid_date is not null, i try with this code:

```
SELECT
sum (case
         when app_id is NOT NULL
         and paid_date is NOT NULL
     then
         1
     else
         0
     end) as PO_Apps
from table_apps
```

I got result PO_Apps : 10 not 1

This is my paid_date column :

[image: paid date]

and app_id:

[image: app_id]

My problem is in the paid_date column when the date contains 00-00-00 is not null. How to solve this? Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: Tag the database you are using

Comment: You have your answer now but please tag the database so later may be you get some options where there is other way to validate a date depending on the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a condition to accept rows when date is not '0000-00-00'

```
SELECT
sum (case when app_id is NOT NULL and paid_date is NOT NULL and paid_date != '0000-00-00' then 1 else 0 end) as PO_Apps
from table_apps
```

Second Use case for this sort of query can be :

```
SELECT count(app_id) as PO_Apps
from table_apps
where paid_date is NOT NULL and paid_date != '0000-00-00'
```

`count(app_id)` will only count not null instances.

Comment: `paid_date is NOT NULL` is not needed, `paid_date != '0000-00-00'` also removes NULLs.

Answer (score 1):

just use count and where condition

```
select count(*) from table_apps where   
paid_date is NOT NULL and paid_date != '0000-00-00' and app_id is NOT NULL
```

Comment: Although it's giving the same result, that's a different use case. OP may want other fields and not necessary filters the whole query like this

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
SELECT count(*) PO_Apps from tablename 
where app_id is NOT NULL and (paid_date is not null or paid_date<>'0000-00-00')
```

Comment: Wouldn't using coalesce in a filter obfuscate any potential to use an index?